# How to filter string from all column from csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x

[csv file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGYXa.jpg)I have a csv file and I need to check all columns to find ? in the csv file and remove those rows.

below is an example

```
Column1 Column 2 Column 3
1 ? 3
2 ?.. 1
? 2 ?.
? 4 4
```

I tried the below however it does not work

```
data = readData(“text.csv”)
print(data)

def Filter(string, substr):
return [str for str in string if
any(sub not in str for sub in substr)]

string = data
substr = [’?’,’?.’,’? ‘,’? ']
filter_data=Filter(string, substr)
```

my code is below to get ouptut in tupples.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def readData(filename) :
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, skipinitialspace=True)
    return [d for d in data.itertuples(index=False, name=None)]

data = readData("problem2.csv")
print(data)

[('18.0', 8, '307.0 ', '130.0 ', '3504.', '12.0', 70, 1, 'chevrolet chevelle malibu'), ('15.0', 8, '350.0 ', '165.0 ', '3693.', '11.5', 70, 1, 'buick skylark 320'), ('18.0', 8, '318.0 ', '150.0 ', '?.', '11.0', 70, 1, 'plymouth satellite'), ('16.0', 8, '304.0 ', '150.0 ', '3433.', '12.0', 70, 1, 'amc rebel sst'), ('17.0', 8, '302.0 ', '140.0 ', '3449.', '10.5', 70, 1, 'ford torino'), ('15.0', 8, '429.0 ', '198.0 ', '4341.', '10.0', 70, 1, 'ford galaxie 500'), ('14.0', 8, '454.0 ', '220.0 ', '4354.', '9.0', 70, 1, 'chevrolet impala'), ('14.0', 8, '440.0 ', '215.0 ', '4312.', '8.5', 70, 1, 'plymouth fury iii'),
```

Next want to remove rows with '?; from all columns to provide the same output in tupples.

Comment: can you share a few rows of the text.csv file please?

Comment: here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZtRobqEUFDjbw2Plq5lLmpe2xfzJc7K6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you try re.replace('?','')

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole row if any entry contains `?`  If you are on a `*nix` or mac, you could do `grep -v '?' text.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My input file is as follows:

```
mpg,cylinder,displace,horsepower,weight,accelerate,year,origin,name
18,8,307,130,3504,12,70,1,chevy malibu
18,8,308,140,?.,14,70,1,plymoth satellite
18,8,309,150,?,15,70,1,ford torino
18,8,310,150,? ,16,70,1,ford galaxy
18,8,310,150, ?,17,70,1,pontiac catalina
18,8,310,150,3505,18,70,1,ford maverick
```

The code to replace any of the following occurrences `['?','?.',' ?','? ']` is as follows:

```
import csv
qs = ['?','?.',' ?','? ']
with open('abc.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        row = ['' if r in qs else r for r in row]
        print (row)
```

The output of this will be as follows:

```
['mpg', 'cylinder', 'displace', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'accelerate', 'year', 'origin', 'name']
['18', '8', '307', '130', '3504', '12', '70', '1', 'chevy malibu']
['18', '8', '308', '140', '', '14', '70', '1', 'plymoth satellite']
['18', '8', '309', '150', '', '15', '70', '1', 'ford torino']
['18', '8', '310', '150', '', '16', '70', '1', 'ford galaxy']
['18', '8', '310', '150', '', '17', '70', '1', 'pontiac catalina']
['18', '8', '310', '150', '3505', '18', '70', '1', 'ford maverick']
```

As you can see values from rows 3 thru 6 got replaced with `''`.

Ran with one more sample dataset:

```
mpg,cylinder,displace,horsepower,weight,accelerate,year,origin,name
18,8,307,130,3504,12,70,1,chevy malibu
18,8,308,140,?.,14,70,1,plymoth satellite
18,8,309,?,3506,15,70,1,ford torino
18,8,310,160,? ,16,70,1,ford galaxy
18,8,311,170,3508, ?,70,1,pontiac catalina
18,8,312,180,3509,18,70,1,ford maverick
```

Output is:

```
['mpg', 'cylinder', 'displace', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'accelerate', 'year', 'origin', 'name']
['18', '8', '307', '130', '3504', '12', '70', '1', 'chevy malibu']
['18', '8', '308', '140', '', '14', '70', '1', 'plymoth satellite']
['18', '8', '309', '', '3506', '15', '70', '1', 'ford torino']
['18', '8', '310', '160', '', '16', '70', '1', 'ford galaxy']
['18', '8', '311', '170', '3508', '', '70', '1', 'pontiac catalina']
['18', '8', '312', '180', '3509', '18', '70', '1', 'ford maverick']
```

In this scenario, the `?` is on various columns. It still addresses the problem.

In case you are looking for all the rows in one go, you can read all the lines into one variable and process it.

```
qs = {'?.':'',' ?':'','? ':'','?':''}
with open('abc.txt') as csv_file:
    lines = csv_file.readlines()
    for i,text in enumerate(lines):
        [text := text.replace(a,b) for a,b in qs.items()]
        lines[i] = text
    print (lines)
```

Your output data will be as follows:

```
['mpg,cylinder,displace,horsepower,weight,accelerate,year,origin,name\n', '18,8,307,130,3504,12,70,1,chevy malibu\n', '18,8,308,140,,14,70,1,plymoth satellite\n', '18,8,309,,3506,15,70,1,ford torino\n', '18,8,310,160,,16,70,1,ford galaxy\n', '18,8,311,170,3508,,70,1,pontiac catalina\n', '18,8,312,180,3509,18,70,1,ford maverick\n']
```

## tuple output

Looks like you are expecting tuples as output.

Here's the code to do it:

```
import csv
qs = {'?.':'',' ?':'','? ':'','?':''}
final_list = []

with open('abc.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        row = ['' if r in qs else r for r in row]
        final_list.append(tuple(row))

print (final_list)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
[('mpg', 'cylinder', 'displace', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'accelerate', 'year', 'origin', 'name'), ('18', '8', '307', '130', '3504', '12', '70', '1', 'chevy malibu'), ('18', '8', '308', '140', '', '14', '70', '1', 'plymoth satellite'), ('18', '8', '309', '', '3506', '15', '70', '1', 'ford torino'), ('18', '8', '310', '160', '', '16', '70', '1', 'ford galaxy'), ('18', '8', '311', '170', '3508', '', '70', '1', 'pontiac catalina'), ('18', '8', '312', '180', '3509', '18', '70', '1', 'ford maverick')]
```

Comment: I am looking for this output in tuples     [('18.0', 8, '307.0 ', '130.0 ', '3504.', '12.0', 70, 1, 'chevrolet chevelle malibu'), ('15.0', 8, '350.0 ', '165.0 ', '3693.', '11.5', 70, 1, 'buick skylark 320'), ('18.0', 8, '318.0 ', '150.0 ', '?.', '11.0', 70, 1, 'plymouth satellite'), ('16.0', 8, '304.0 ', '150.0 ', '3433.', '12.0', 70, 1, 'amc rebel sst'),

Comment: can you please provide sample input data, expected output data. That way I can know what you are looking for. Your question is not very clear and it takes a while to guess what you are thinking.

Comment: please add the code in the question section

Comment: see the new response.

Comment: thanks how do i exclude the header from the output

Comment: `final_list = final_list[1:]`

Comment: or before the for loop starts, you can give `next(csv_reader, None)` That will skip the first row and process the rest.

Comment: Awesome!!! thanks for all the help Joe.  I am new to python would you pls recommend any good books for python

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/  or https://realpython.com/ or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-programming-language/ will help you. I think these websites provide lots of great tools for you to learn. Additionally, watch https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLi01XoE8jYohWFPpC17Z-wWhPOSuh8Er-

Comment: Dont forget to upvote the answer if you think it helped you with the project

Comment: Thanks Joe this his very helpful!

Comment: currently the values with ? are marked as ' '. Can i remove the tupple list which has ?

Comment: Yes you can. The code needs minor adjustment. Or you can add a line to the code to look for `''` and pop them out.